# Why are double parentheses needed with std::is_same

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to use `std::is_same` to verify the underlying type of a strongly typed enum and I noticed a strange situation where I needed to use double parentheses, but I don't understand why. I've reduced the example down to as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert((std::is_same<unsigned int,uint32_t>::value == true)); // OK
    assert((std::is_same<unsigned int,uint32_t>::value) == true); // OK
    //assert(std::is_same<unsigned int,uint32_t>::value == true); // Compile error
    static_assert(std::is_same<unsigned int,uint32_t>::value == true, "BAD"); // OK
    return 0;
}
```

Compile error:

```
isSameAssert.cpp:9:62: error: macro "assert" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
     assert(std::is_same<unsigned int,uint32_t>::value == true); // Compile error
                                                              ^
isSameAssert.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
isSameAssert.cpp:9:5: error: ‘assert’ was not declared in this scope
     assert(std::is_same<unsigned int,uint32_t>::value == true); // Compile error
     ^
make: *** [build/isSameAssert] Error 1
```

Could anyone explain this or point me to a reference that does?

Comment: That's because `assert()` is a macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `assert` is a macro, the expression `assert(std::is_same<unsigned int,uint32_t>::value == true);` seems to call `assert` with two parameters due to the comma between `int` and `uint32_t` so the compiler complains that `assert` takes only one parameter, but two were supplied.

Indeed, putting it again in parenthesis solves this issue.